# SSIS convert date in int format to Date (yyyy/mm/dd hh:mi:ss)

Tags: ssis

In SSIS I have date in int format 2012123023
need to convert it into 2012/12/30 23:00:00
please help!

Comment: which version of SSIS are you using? 2005/2008/2012?

Answer (score 0):

I have used this function in SQL Server, although, I'm not SSIS expert so I'm not sure how you implement it in the SSIS package.

I would assume that you can create the function in the database and then call it from SSIS.

Edited to work for your test case, it does assume that the number is always in the same format though.

```
--SELECT [dbo].[ConvertIntToDate](2012123023)


-- =============================================
-- Author:      Richard Andrews
-- Create date: 12/10/2012
-- Description: Safely attempts to convert an int into a date
-- =============================================
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertIntToDate] 
(
    @InputNumber INT 
)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    IF @InputNumber IS NULL
        BEGIN
            RETURN NULL
        END

    DECLARE @Result DATETIME    
    DECLARE @StringDate NVARCHAR(50)
    SET @StringDate = CAST(@InputNumber AS NVARCHAR(50))

    IF LEN(@StringDate) <> 10
        BEGIN
            RETURN NULL
        END

    DECLARE @FormattedStringDate NVARCHAR(50)    
    SET @FormattedStringDate = SUBSTRING(@StringDate, 1, 4)
        + '-' + SUBSTRING(@StringDate, 5, 2)
        + '-' + SUBSTRING(@StringDate, 8, 2)
        + ' ' + SUBSTRING(@StringDate, 9, 2) + ':00'

    IF ISDATE(@FormattedStringDate) = 0
        BEGIN
            RETURN NULL
        END

    SET @Result = CONVERT(DATETIME, @FormattedStringDate)

    RETURN @Result 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't look like a valid SQL Server date format (at least one that SQL Server would understand).

If you are 100% sure that the string would always be on this format, you can do something like

```
DECLARE @mydate VARCHAR(20)
SET @mydate=2012123023 
SELECT 
CAST(
SUBSTRING(@mydate,1,4)+'-'+SUBSTRING(@mydate,5,2)+'-'+SUBSTRING(@mydate,7,2)+' '+SUBSTRING(@mydate,9,2)+':00'
AS DATETIME)
```